# calculations in the report vs calculation in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, database-performance

I'm producing a report that has a calculation as one of the desired columns:

```
SELECT
   ....
   sum(SFLI.PLANNEDVOLUME) * PTS.KILOGRAMSPERUNIT as [WEIGHT],
FROM
   ....
GROUP BY
   ....
```

Another developer from my team, said that it would be better to move the calculation to the report rather than leave it in the stored procedure, because it is producing a bad execution plan. I did some research and it seems that moving calculations to the report can be bad for large datasets.

So my question, is it super bad leave the calculation in the stored procedure? I'm pretty sure that SQL Server is smart enough to do things in parallel and even the execution plan won't be that bad. Am I wrong?

PS: Without the grouping, we're talking about 250k rows, that grouped produces < 250 rows.

Comment: This depends on so much... but have you tested which is faster in YOUR environment? Another consideration is code reuse. If it makes sense to leave the data Not aggregated so it can be called and aggregated differently by other applications and reports, then there's that consideration.

Comment: 250 k rows is tiny. Also a bad execution plan can be improved. And a bad execution plan is not always a bad thing. So show us the execution plan and maybe we can help there.

Comment: No reuse, a dedicated stored procedure for a report only.

Comment: Please add the execution plan so it can be analyzed

Comment: There is no one true answer here.  It is my firm belief that the presentation layer should be as thin as possible.  Consider the following:  I had a client which added a new Risk Rating.  They had to review, modify and validate thousands of reports while I simply added the new item into my mapping table.

Comment: If you're producing a "bad execution plan" with just 250k rows, then it likely has to do with a lack of proper indexes for your query _or_ something about the query is poorly written (e.g. it's not as simple as select... from... group by...). SQL Server is fine for basic aggregation like this and works fast enough.

Comment: Databases are designed to deal with data whereas Reporting is for the presentation of data. I've dealt with huge datasets and the calculations, that easily fail a report, databases can just deal that way more easily. So based on my 10+year experience or reporting, always do calculations with data in databases unless it's too simple.

Comment: I have the same opinion.

Comment: All we have to go on is 'a bad execution plan'. I'll add to that and says it's 'bad' to put common business logic in a report when it can go into the database

Comment: can suggest to have a clean  raw data for reporting... clean means no bad data... raw means no calculation and you do it at the report... if you calculations on your dataset you simply cannot use this for other reports.. the raw the better

Comment: I think you need to get the execution plans.  
One with sum(SFLI.PLANNEDVOLUME) * PTS.KILOGRAMSPERUNIT as [WEIGHT] and the other with 
sum(SFLI.PLANNEDVOLUME) AS TOTAL_VOLUME, PTS.KILOGRAMSPERUNIT.  
I can't imagine that with 250K rows you are going to face any serious challenges unless the table is extremely wide and the hardware is poor.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the calculation to the report just means the SSRS web server will do the work by code (C? C++?) instead of SQL running it through the db engine optimizer. If you're doing a lot of string manipulation then SSRS might be able to do it faster than SQL, but in your case it looks like you're doing a numeric calculation, and I'd definitely let SQL handle that unless someone tells you that you're bringing the server to its knees. If you are, you can also look into running the query as a nightly batch process into a datamart. As @scsimon says, it really depends on how fast each scenario runs in your environment, so you can't depend on your coworker's rule-of-thumb.

Personally, I have a lot of reports that use the same or similar data sets, so it makes more sense for me to have the calculations in SQL because I can change all reports by changing the underlying proc.